# Character slowly falling through floor instead of coming to a complete stop

Tags: python, pygame

My character is slowly falling through the ground instead of a complete stop. The collision code is in the 4th function called def update():. I do have a second file that mainly deals with sprite collision which is where the self.player imports are coming from but it shouldn't have much of an impact on the problem.

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from sprites import *

class Game:
 def __init__(self):
    # ==============================================================================================================
    # initialize game window, etc
    pg.init()
    pg.mixer.init()
    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(SCREEN)
    pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
    self.spritesheet = Spritesheet(Mario)
    self.running = True

def new(self):
    # ==============================================================================================================
    # start a new game
    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    self.player = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.player = Player(self)
    self.level()
    self.run()

def run(self):
    # ==============================================================================================================
    # Game Loop
    self.playing = True
    while self.playing:
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        self.events()
        self.update()
        self.draw()


def update(self):
    # Game Loop - Update
    self.all_sprites.update()

    # ==============================================================================================================
    # COLLISION BETWEEN PLAYER AND PLATFORMS GROUP
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)

    # ==============================================================================================================
    # GOING RIGHTWARDS COLLISION
    if self.player.vel.x > 0:
        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if self.player.rect.right > hit.rect.right:
                    self.player.rect.right = hit.rect.right
                    self.player.vel.x = 0
                    self.player.rect.midbottom = self.player.pos

    # ==============================================================================================================
    # GOING LEFT WARDS COLLISION
    elif self.player.vel.x < 0:
        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if self.player.rect.left < hit.rect.left:
                    self.player.rect.right = hit.rect.left
                    self.player.vel.x = 0
                    self.player.rect.midbottom = self.player.pos

    # ==============================================================================================================
    # ASCENDING COLLISION
    elif self.player.vel.y < 0:
        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if self.player.rect.top > hit.rect.bottom:
                    self.player.rect.top = hit.rect.bottom
                    self.player.vel.y = 0
                    self.player.jumping = False
                    self.player.rect.midbottom = self.player.pos

    # ==============================================================================================================
    # FALLING COLLISION
    elif self.player.vel.y > 0:
        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if hit.rect.top:
                    self.player.rect.bottom = hit.rect.top
                    self.player.vel.y = 0
                    self.player.jumping = False
                    self.player.rect.midbottom = self.player.pos



def events(self):
    # Game Loop - events
    for event in pg.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            self.playing = False
            self.running = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                self.player.jump()
        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                self.player.jump_cut()

def level(self):
    # ==============================================================================================================
    # MAKE LEVEL
    self.levelsss = level
    y=0
    for row in self.levelsss:
        x = 0
        for col in row:
            if col == "1":
                block(self, x, y)
            x += 1
        y+= 1


def draw(self):
    # ==============================================================================================================
    # DRAW SPRITES
    self.screen.fill(DEEP_SKY_BLUE)
    self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pg.display.flip()

def show_start_screen(self):
    # game splasrh/start screen
    pass

def show_go_screen(self):
    # game over/continue
    pass

g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
  g.new()
  g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Please condense your code down to a [mre]. 
It's a pain to read line after line of irrelevant code. 
The exercise of creating a MRE forces you to look at your code and try to isolate the problem, which can often help you figure out the issue without even having to ask on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement separate collisions test for the vertical and horizontal movement. In your code, the collision test for the y axis is on executed, if the player doesn't move along the x axis:

> ```py
> if self.player.vel.x > 0:
>    # [...]
> elif self.player.vel.x < 0:
>    # [...]
> elif self.player.vel.y < 0:
>    # [...]
> elif self.player.vel.y > 0:
>    # [...]
> ```

Change the 2nd `elif` to an `if`

```py
# test for collision in x direction
if self.player.vel.x > 0:
    # [...]
elif self.player.vel.x < 0:
    # [...]

# test for collision in y direction
if self.player.vel.y < 0:
    # [...]
elif self.player.vel.y > 0:
    # [...]
```

If the horizontal movement is very large, you can achieve an improvement by repeating the collision test after handling the collisions in the x direction:

```py
hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
if hits:
    if self.player.vel.x > 0:
        # [...]
    elif self.player.vel.x < 0:
        # [...]


hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
if hits:
    if self.player.vel.y < 0:
        # [...]
    elif self.player.vel.y > 0:
        # [...]
```

Comment: My character doesn't fall through the floor, but now for when my character hits the top of his head on a block he instantly teleports on top of the platform.

Comment: @t0rror Sorry, but you've to debug your application yourself. I can only help you with the obvious mistakes.

Comment: No worries I figured it out